# Facebook Session S4 vs. Nexus

Tags: android, facebook, galaxy, galaxy-nexus

I'm having trouble opening a Facebook Session on a Samsung Galaxy S4 (Running 4.2.2).

The same application works on a Nexus running 4.2.1 and also on the emulator running 4.2.2.

I followed the [Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/) provided by Facebook and determined that the session variable never gets opened.

Is this maybe due to additional security on the S4 or any conflicting Samsung software? And how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not with the Android version nor the device or software.

All developers needs to be registered with a Facebook Developers account.  To add a developer go to your [Applications Page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/), and in the Roles section click Edit Roles.  Now you can add people who will be using your application during the development phase including Admin, Developers and Testers.